# How can I make users ONLY input decimal?

Tags: java, input, decimal

So I am very new to java and struggling with my class ... here's what I thought would work:

```
double costPerKiloHr = 0; //sets value to 0

    //tests to make sure a number was inputted

        try {
            costPerKiloHr = Double.parseDouble(
                this.costPerKiloHrText.getText());
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please input a dollar amount including cents",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Does this not work? What error message do you get?

Comment: What problem are you having with your solution?

Comment: It allows numbers, decimals or not.  I'm sorry, I should have stated that.

Comment: You can use a regex expression to validate if the text is a valid number before you try to parse it - you can also provide a NumberFormat if you want to be able to obtain the number even if the user types the dollar symbol or anything of the sort.

Comment: So how does it not work? I assume you mean the only thing you don't want is alpha text, but all other numeric values are valid? So for example, all integers are valid (counting, natural and negative) as well as decimals? You may be better off with a regular expression.

Comment: You can't.  Your users can type 6.00 if they want.  What you can do is ask for an integer, and divide by 100 to get cents.  Your users can still type 600.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to check for a match for at least 1 numerical value after the decimal.

```
    String input = scanner.next();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if(matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println("True");
    }else{
        System.out.println("False");
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1.0   True
ASB   False
0.25  True
1     False
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make users to input what you want, if you are not a mage or smth. But you can edit the code that accept user input. There can be a huge difference: I don't know what are you using as input. I noticed you're using `JOptionPane` so I guess you use swing.

In swing there is `JTextField` and you can control it's content like this:

```
    final JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                buffer.append(c);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            field.setText(buffer.toString());
        }
    });
```

If you are using `InputStream` you should interpret `byte` pairs  as `chars` and then filter out non-digit values. Declaration of delimiters is required that way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Swing (a safe bet given the use of `JOptionPane`), you can have the user type into a `javax.swing.JFormattedTextField`... This is an extension of the `JTextField` widget that takes a Formatter object that defines what is and isn't acceptible. It can be configured (through `Formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false)`) to never let the user type in an invalid string.

So a formatter for an arbitrary regular expression might look something like this:

```
public class RegExFormatter extends DefaultFormatter {
        protected Matcher matcher;
        public RegExFormatter(String regex) {
        setOverwriteMode(false);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        matcher = p.matcher(""); // initial field contents
    }

    @Override
    public Object stringToValue(String string) throws ParseException {
        if (string == null || string.trim().equals(""))
            return null;
        matcher.reset(string);

        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new ParseException("Input did not match regex", 0);
        }

        return super.stringToValue(string);  // default returns this string; see docs!
    }

}
```

Then you use this in your code like this:

```
    String regex = "^[1-9]*[0-9](\\.\\d*)?$";  // change this to taste!
    RegExFormatter ref = new RegExFormatter(regex);
    ref.setAllowsInvalid(false);
    JFormattedTextField field1 = new JFormattedTextField(ref);
```